# Pass Arguments through Onaction with CheckBoxes

Tags: excel, vba

So i have been at this for a while now and I have searched through many websites and forums but alas I can not find a solution to my issue.

I am trying to add arguments to an `.OnAction` event for a `Checkbox`

So.. For example

```
Dim chk as Checkbox
    With chk
        .name = "chk" & .TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -7).Text
        .Caption = ""
        .Left = cel.Left + (cel.Width / 2 - chk.Width / 2) + 7
        .Top = cel.Top + (cel.Height / 2 - chk.Height / 2)
        .OnAction = "CheckboxHandle(chk)"
    End With
```

So if I was trying to call this sub -> `Public Sub CheckboxHandle(obj As CheckBox)`

It requries a `CheckBox Object` to be able to run *(this can change to a shape/Object if necessary)*

**THINGS I HAVE TRIED**

Changing the data type to object and shape however i couldn't find a way to pass it through

Variations of the below statements

`"""CheckboxHandle(chk)"""`

`"'CheckboxHandle" ""chk"" '"`

`Application.caller` then looping through `objects` to find the `object` whit that name *(this takes way too long as I have over 300 Checkboxes)*

**CONTEXT**

In case the context helps I am trying to add a checkbox to every cell in a range and then have each one call the same method when they are clicked. I need the `OnAction` to send an `Object` as i look for the `TopleftCell` of the `Object` to change the colour of the adjacent cells

**IN CASE IT IS HELPFUL**
here is the method i would like to call from the `OnAction` Event

```
Public Sub CheckboxHandle(obj As CheckBox)
Dim rng As Range
'Sneaky sneaky changes
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'For Loop to go through each of the cells to the left of the check box
For Each rng In Range(obj.TopLeftCell, obj.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, -7))
    With rng
        'if the checkbox is checked
        If obj.Value = -1 Then
            .Interior.Color = RGB(202, 226, 188)
            'Adds the date and the person so you know who did the edit
            obj.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now & " by " & Application.username
        Else
            'if it isn't checked
            .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            'removes the edit name and date
            obj.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
        End If
    End With
Next rng
'Shows all the changes at the same time
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Changes the value of the progress bar to represent the project completion
    If obj.Value = -1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value + 1 / 207
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value - 1 / 207
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated

-Sebic0

Comment: Maybe try `.OnAction = "Checkboxhanlde(" & chk & ")"`

Comment: Unfortunately not :( thank you for your suggestion tho

Comment: Why looping with Application.Caller? Set obj = Sheet1.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)

Comment: Because I did not know that the `CheckBoxes` property took an `Index`! Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can pass an object via the `OnAction`. The `OnAction`-property is a string holding the name of a Sub (plus parameter).

You could try to pass the name of the checkBox  instead. Note that you have to enclose the name of the checkbox in double quotes, so that you would get something like. `CheckboxHandle "chk123"`:

```
 .OnAction = "'CheckboxHandle """ & .Name & """'"
```

And change your Action-routine

```
Public Sub CheckboxHandle(chbBoxName as string)
    dim chk as CheckBox
    Set chk = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(chkBoxName)
    (...)
```

Comment: Also OP has typo: should have **`CheckboxHandle`** not `Checkboxhanlde`

Comment: Great! Thank you! This has helped a lot.. I have tried what you said however the `chk` still is set to `nothing` Also @Sam i have amended the post on your observation thank you :)

Comment: I will mark as the answer as it has solved my initial issue. Thank you so much